# Not able to render a JSON object to DOJO StoreSeries

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am working on a DOJO Project. As of now I have a MySql Database, a php code, and a JS script for the front end. The php code reads values from the database, encodes a JSON object of the same and sends to the client side. The JS script should take render this JSON object and plot a LINE chart.

php code -

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysite.com","root","1234","dojo1");
$i=0;
$arr = array();
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test");
    while($i<10 && $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $j=$row['a'];
        $arr[]=array('id'=>$j);
        //$arr[]=$j;
        $i=$i+1;

    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $temp= json_encode($arr,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    echo $temp;
}
?>
```

The JS code is -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

<head>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src='dojo/dojo.js'></script>

<script>
var chart;
var store;

require(["dojo/request/xhr",
    "dojo/json",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojo/store/Observable",
    "dojox/charting/StoreSeries",
    "dojox/charting/Chart2D", 
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines", 
    "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",    
    "dojo/domReady!",
    "dojox/charting/StoreSeries"], 

    function(xhr, JSON, Memory, Observable, StoreSeries, Chart, DataSeries) {

    xhr("dojo1.php",{
        handleAs: "json"
    }).then(function(data){ 

        //var data = eval(data1);
        var i=0;
       // for(i=0;i<5;i++)
         //alert(data[i].id);
         console.log(data);
        store = Observable(new Memory({data: data}));

        chart = new Chart("graph");

        chart.addPlot("default", {type: "Lines", markers:true});

        chart.addAxis("x", {title:"Time", titleOrientation:"away"});
        chart.addAxis("y", {vertical: true, majorTick: false, title:"Load"});

        //chart.addSeries("Series X", [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]);

       chart.addSeries("Series Y", new StoreSeries(store, { query: {}}, "id"));
      //  chart.addSeries("Series Z", new DataSeries(store, { query: {} }, "id"));

        chart.render();
    });         
});


</script>
<div id="graph" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; "></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JSON object looks like this -

```
[{"id":"20"},{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"1"},{"id":"1"},{"id":"1"},{"id":"1"}]
```

I experimented a lot to find a solution out. The problems I am facing are - 
 1. If the values in the JS script are hard-coded, the chart comes out to be fine. (Series X)
 2. If the values in the php script are hardcoded and sent as a JSON object, and the JS script reads the values, yet again the chart comes out to be fine. (Series Y).
 3. The problem occurs when I send the data read from the sql databse as a JSON object from php. The Series Y does not work, and the UI shows only 2 axes without any plotting.
 4. If I remove the "JSON_FORCE_OBJECT" term from the encoding part in the php file, nothing at all happens in Series Y, i.e. not even axes appear and the console gives a big list of errors regarding "Promises" and "Object Deferred".
The job to be done is quite trivial, i.e to read a JSON object and plot it on a LINE graph. But I am stuck on this problem since 2 weeks. Kindly help in the same.